# camel cxf consume service

Tags: soap, apache-camel, wsdl

I have a very simple Soap service with a String parameter and returns a String.

With Maven I've generated the corresponding classes from the WSDL.
I imported the wsdl into SOAP-UI and I made a mock.
I started the mock and I made a test case which sends and receives the response correctly.

I created a junit test with a camel route
and that's where it comes problems.
I can't build the url that would allow me to invoke my mock
I first simply put `"cxf://http://localhost:8088/mockws_traca?DefaultOperationName=MajTracaDMI&wsdlURL=ws_traca.wsdl"`
without success.
I added the service class
`"&serviceClass="+WsTraca.class.getName()`
which causes an invalid service error `{http://localhost/ws_traca/wsdl/}WsTraca`
after debug step by step I found the name of the generated service that I added
`"&serviceName={http://localhost/ws_traca/wsdl/}ws_traca"`
he made the same mistake with the type of port
I did not find a parameter to specify the type of port so I added its name
`"&portName={http://localhost/ws_traca/wsdl/}ws_tracaSoapPort"`

My routeBuilder

```
protected final RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception{
       return new RouteBuilder() {

         @Override
         public void configure() throws Exception{

            from("direct:start")
            .setHeader(CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAME, constant("MajTracaDMI"))

            .to("cxf://http://localhost:8088/mockws_traca"
               + "?serviceClass="+WsTraca.class.getName()
               + "&portName={http://localhost/ws_traca/wsdl/}ws_tracaSoapPort"
               + "&serviceName={http://localhost/ws_traca/wsdl/}ws_traca"
               + "&wsdlURL=ws_traca.wsdl"
               );
         }

       };
    }
```

the wsdl :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- Generated 05/15/19 by Microsoft SOAP Toolkit WSDL File Generator, Version 3.00.1325.0 --> 
<definitions
    name='ws_traca'
    targetNamespace='http://localhost/ws_traca/wsdl/'
    xmlns:wsdlns='http://localhost/ws_traca/wsdl/'
    xmlns:typens='http://localhost/ws_traca/type/'
    xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/'
    xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
    xmlns:stk='http://schemas.microsoft.com/soap-toolkit/wsdl-extension'
    xmlns:dime='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/04/dime/wsdl/'
    xmlns:ref='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/04/reference/'
    xmlns:content='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/04/content-type/'
    xmlns:wsdl='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'
    xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'>

    <types>
        <schema
            targetNamespace='http://localhost/ws_traca/type/'
            xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
            xmlns:SOAP-ENC='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'
            xmlns:wsdl='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'
            elementFormDefault='qualified'>

            <import namespace='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
            <import namespace='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'/>
            <import namespace='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/04/reference/'/>
            <import namespace='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/04/content-type/'/>

        </schema>
    </types>

    <message name='ws_traca.MajTracaDMI'>
        <part name='c_xml' type='xsd:string'/>
    </message>

    <message name='ws_traca.MajTracaDMIResponse'>
        <part name='Result' type='xsd:string'/>
    </message>

    <message name='ws_traca.GetTracaDMI'>
        <part name='c_xml' type='xsd:string'/>
    </message>

    <message name='ws_traca.GetTracaDMIResponse'>
        <part name='Result' type='xsd:string'/>
    </message>

    <message name='ws_traca.Ping'>
        <part name='c_chaine' type='xsd:string'/>
    </message>

    <message name='ws_traca.PingResponse'>
        <part name='Result' type='xsd:string'/>
    </message>

    <message name='ws_traca.InfoDll'>
        <part name='cXml' type='xsd:string'/>
    </message>

    <message name='ws_traca.InfoDllResponse'>
        <part name='Result' type='xsd:string'/>
    </message>

    <portType name='ws_tracaSoapPort'>

        <operation name='MajTracaDMI' parameterOrder='c_xml'>
            <input message='wsdlns:ws_traca.MajTracaDMI'/>
            <output message='wsdlns:ws_traca.MajTracaDMIResponse'/>
        </operation>

        <operation name='GetTracaDMI' parameterOrder='c_xml'>
            <input message='wsdlns:ws_traca.GetTracaDMI'/>
            <output message='wsdlns:ws_traca.GetTracaDMIResponse'/>
        </operation>

        <operation name='Ping' parameterOrder='c_chaine'>
            <input message='wsdlns:ws_traca.Ping'/>
            <output message='wsdlns:ws_traca.PingResponse'/>
        </operation>

        <operation name='InfoDll' parameterOrder='cXml'>
            <input message='wsdlns:ws_traca.InfoDll'/>
            <output message='wsdlns:ws_traca.InfoDllResponse'/>
        </operation>

    </portType>

    <binding name='ws_tracaSoapBinding' type='wsdlns:ws_tracaSoapPort' >

        <stk:binding preferredEncoding='UTF-8'/>
        <soap:binding style='rpc' transport='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http'/>

        <operation name='MajTracaDMI'>
            <soap:operation soapAction='http://localhost/ws_traca/action/ws_traca.MajTracaDMI'/>
            <input>
                <soap:body
                    namespace='http://localhost/ws_traca/message/'
                    parts='c_xml'/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body
                    namespace='http://localhost/ws_traca/message/'
                    parts='Result'/>
            </output>
        </operation>

        <operation name='GetTracaDMI'>
            <soap:operation soapAction='http://localhost/ws_traca/action/ws_traca.GetTracaDMI'/>
            <input>
                <soap:body
                    namespace='http://localhost/ws_traca/message/'
                    parts='c_xml'/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body
                    namespace='http://localhost/ws_traca/message/'
                    parts='Result'/>
            </output>
        </operation>

        <operation name='Ping'>
            <soap:operation soapAction='http://localhost/ws_traca/action/ws_traca.Ping'/>
            <input>
                <soap:body
                    namespace='http://localhost/ws_traca/message/'
                    parts='c_chaine'/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body
                    namespace='http://localhost/ws_traca/message/'
                    parts='Result'/>
            </output>
        </operation>

        <operation name='InfoDll'>
            <soap:operation soapAction='http://localhost/ws_traca/action/ws_traca.InfoDll'/>
            <input>
                <soap:body
                    namespace='http://localhost/ws_traca/message/'
                    parts='cXml'/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body
                    namespace='http://localhost/ws_traca/message/'
                    parts='Result'/>
            </output>
        </operation>

    </binding>

    <service name='ws_traca' >
        <port name='ws_tracaSoapPort' binding='wsdlns:ws_tracaSoapBinding' >
            <soap:address location='http://localhost/ws_trunk/ws_traca.WSDL'/>
        </port>
    </service>

</definitions>
```

I've now an error on WsTraca that not an interface

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateProducerException: Failed to create Producer for endpoint: Endpoint[cxf://http://SAP5223897:8088/mockws_traca?portName=%7Bhttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fws_traca%2Fwsdl%2F%7Dws_tracaSoapPort&serviceClass=localhost.ws_traca.wsdl.WsTraca&serviceName=%7Bhttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fws_traca%2Fwsdl%2F%7Dws_traca&wsdlURL=ws_traca.wsdl]. Reason: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: localhost.ws_traca.wsdl.WsTraca is not an interface
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doGetProducer(ProducerCache.java:380)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.acquireProducer(ProducerCache.java:107)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.startProducer(ProducerCache.java:138)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.doStart(SendProcessor.java:163)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:67)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:54)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:56)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:70)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.doStart(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.doStart(TraceInterceptor.java:444)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:67)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:54)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:56)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:70)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.doStart(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:67)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:54)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:56)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:70)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.doStart(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:982)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:67)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:54)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:56)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:70)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultChannel.doStart(DefaultChannel.java:149)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:67)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:54)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:56)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:82)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doStart(MulticastProcessor.java:920)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:67)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:54)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:56)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:70)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.doStart(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:67)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:54)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:56)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:70)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.doStart(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:67)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:54)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:56)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.startChildService(RouteService.java:245)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:142)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWarmUpRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:1843)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(DefaultCamelContext.java:1771)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:1556)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:1448)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:1338)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:67)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:54)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:1316)
    at org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport.startCamelContext(CamelTestSupport.java:344)
    at org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport.doSetUp(CamelTestSupport.java:228)
    at org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport.setUp(CamelTestSupport.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:47)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:18)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: localhost.ws_traca.wsdl.WsTraca is not an interface
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass0(Proxy.java:470)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:690)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.create(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:171)
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfEndpoint.createClient(CxfEndpoint.java:455)
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfProducer.<init>(CxfProducer.java:71)
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfEndpoint.createProducer(CxfEndpoint.java:153)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.InterceptSendToEndpoint.createProducer(InterceptSendToEndpoint.java:93)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doGetProducer(ProducerCache.java:376)
    ... 83 more
```